# how to give condition for matching expiry_date is greater than & equal to current date(laravel)

Tags: php, laravel, date, conditional-statements

i want to fetch data from database based on condition as 'expires_on' should be 
'>=' 'current_date'.
this is my code:

```
    $date = new Carbon;
    $news = DB::table('feed_news')
            ->select('*')
            ->where('expires_on', '>=' ,$date)
            ->orderBy('news_date','DESC')
            ->get();
```

my problem is :

when i do dd($news), it returns me all data based on expires_on '>' current_date 
but not equal to current_date.

Comment: Try whereDate and whereBetween function in query

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`whereDate()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#where-clauses) method:

```
DB::table('feed_news')->whereDate('expires_on', '>=', $date->toDateString())
    ->latest('news_date')
    ->get();
```